# Package Development: Multiple files or Single File

Tags: r, r-package

I've been poking through a bunch of different packages and I'm noticing that there really isn't a clear and concise method for function storage. Some package authors pack all of them in one file while other authors split them into individual files.

I've read a number of package creation guides but none of them provide specific guidelines or suggestions.

Would love to hear your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The best reference I have found on the topic thus far is from [Hadley Wickham's R book draft](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Package-basics). 
Quoting from there:

> It's up to you how you arrange your functions into files, but I suggest grouping related functions into a single file. My rule of thumb is that if I can't remember which file a function lives in, I probably need to split them up into more files - having one function per file is perfectly reasonable, particularly if the functions are large or have a lot of documentation.

Answer (score 9):

I use one function per file. It helps me in the developing stage because I can `source` individual file (CTRL+R+S in Eclipse) and have a changed function handy. I also prefer changing tabs than scrolling up and down a single file. But at the end of the day it probably depends on what you're used to and what tools you use for development.

Comment: Same for me and for the same reason. Only functions I keep in one file are `plot.` `print.` and so. Tbh, is there any reason why you wouldn't store functions in separate files?

Comment: @SachaEpskamp If I have many small functions, I collate them in one file. Sorry for a bit late answer. :)